# what does "-m tcp" mean in this iptables rule?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables), it's an unusual but harmless explicit invocation of the `tcp` iptables module; this module is implicitly invoked when `-p tcp` (TCP protocol) is specified, and only works when `-p tcp` is specified anyway, but apparently whoever wrote system-config-firewall's rule generator believed in the belt-and-suspenders theory of reliability.

Comment: ip{,6}tables-save adds it explicitly by default.

Comment: This still does not explain what the module actually does though?